# Ubuntu 20.04 Language Input fail to launch

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support, ibus

So I have installed Chinese and Japanese in addition to the default English input. After my first installation both appeared to work correctly, i.e. the Japanese input would register hiragana input, with kanji suggestions next to my input.
However after I restarted my machine, even when I switched to my Chinese/Japanese input method, English is the only option. What have I done wrong? Any suggestion to what I can do? Thank you very much

edit: as suggested, running `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` returns `[('xkb', 'us'), ('ibus', 'pinyin'), ('ibus', 'mozc-jp')]`

[Switched to Chinese keyboard, still can't type in Chinese](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJ2GJ.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what this terminal command outputs: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson thank you for the edit suggestion, this is my first time posting on Stack Exchange so I apologize for the lack of attention.

Comment: Then can you also show us what these commands output: 1. `env | grep -E 'XMOD|_IM'` 2. `dpkg-query -W ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson running 1 gives `GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
QT4_IM_MODULE=fcitx
XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=fcitx
QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx` and 2 gives `ibus-gtk:amd64 1.5.22-2ubuntu2.1
ibus-gtk3:amd64 1.5.22-2ubuntu2.1`

Comment: Then open _Language Support_, change _Keyboard input method system_ to "IBus", and reboot.

Comment: @Gunnar Thank you, it fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Great to hear! :)